# Reset cursor in App.xaml.cs, on DispatcherUnhandledException

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible (if yes how is it possible) to reset the cursor in the App.xaml.cs when the DispatcherUnhandledException event occurs.

To clean up after something unexpected happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the mouse cursor and you want to prevent the app from crashing:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" 
             DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException">
  <Application.Resources>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  // resets the cursor
  Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;

  // prevents the app from crashing
  e.Handled = true;
}
```